# PDF Optimization Acrobat vs. Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I have a PDF file that I would like to optimize. I am receiving the file from an outside source so I don't have the means to recreate it from the beginning.

When I open the file in Acrobat and query the resources, it says that the fonts in the file take up 90%+ of the space. If I save the file as postscript and then save the postscript file to an optimized PDF, the file is significantly smaller (upwards of 80% smaller) and the fonts are still embedded.

I am trying to recreate these results with ghostscript. I have tried various permutations of options with pswrite and pdfwrite but what happens is when I do the initial conversion from PDF to Postscript, the text gets converted to an image. When I convert back to PDF the font references are gone so I end up with a PDF file that has 'imaged' text rather than actual fonts.

The file contains 22 embedded custom Type1 fonts which I have. I have added the fonts to the ghostscript search path and proved that ghostscript can find them with:

```
gs \
 -I/home/nauc01 
 -sFONTPATH=/home/nauc01/fonts/Type1 \
 -o 3783QP.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -g5950x8420 \
 -c "200 700 moveto" \
 -c "/3783QP findfont 60 scalefont setfont" \
 -c "(TESTING !!!!!!) show showpage"
```

The resulting file has the font correctly embedded.

I have also tried using ghostscript to go from PDF to PDF like this:

```
gs \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -sNOPAUSE \
 -I/home/nauc01 \
 -dBATCH \
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer \
 -CompressFonts=true \
 -dSubsetFonts=true \
 -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
  input.pdf
```

but the output is usually larger than the input and I can't view the file in anything but ghostscript (adobe reader gives "Object label badly formatted").

I can't provide the original file because they contain confidential information but I will try to answer any questions that need to be answered regarding them.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Acrobat does what you need, I don't understand the desire to recreate it with ghostscript. Surely Acrobat can do batch conversions.

Comment: @luserdroog I need to run this in a *nix environment. I only have Acrobat for windows. I believe Acrobat is available for *nix but I was hoping I wouldn't have to purchase something for this job as it will be a temporary solution. I may end up having to purchase it if all else fails. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use pswrite. As you've discovered this will render text. instead use the ps2write device which retains fonts and text.

You don't say which version of Ghostscript you are using but I would recommend you use a recent one.

One point; Ghostscript isn't 'optimising' the PDF the way Acrobat does, its re-creating it. The original PDF is fully interpreted to produce a sequence of operations that mark the page, pdfwrite (and ps2write) then make a new file which only has those operations inside.

If you choose to subset fonts, then only the required glyphs will be included. If the original PDF contains extraneous information (Adobe Illustrator, for example, usually embeds a complete copy of the .ai file) then this will be discarded. This *may* result in a smaller file, or it may not.

Note that pdfwrite does not support compressed xref and some other later features at present, so some files may well get bigger.

I would personally *not* go via ps2write, since this just adds another layer of prcoessing and discarding of information. I would just use pdfwrite to create a new PDF file. If you find files for which this does not work (using current code) then you should raise a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com so that someone can address the problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. I appreciate the explanation.

I am using 9.04. 

I just ran it again with:
    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sNOPAUSE -I/home/nauc01 -dBATCH  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -CompressFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf

input.pdf = 6182k
opt_printer.pdf = 1720k

The output file won't display in Adobe Reader. It give the "Object label badly formatted" error and all of the pages are blank. I can view it in gsview but the fonts are not correct.

Comment: I ran a PDF file that I downloaded from the internet. The output file was larger than the input but the file was viewable in Adobe Reader. I am starting to think that some of the custom Type1 fonts are corrupted.

I added entries to the Fontmap.GS file that pointed to the .pfb files. Could this be an issue?

Thanks again.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be an issue, *unless* the original PDF has fonts that aren't embedded. Like I said it is possible for the file to get bigger, without seeing the original I can't really comment further than that. I can certainly create PDF files here that work fine in Acrobat, so it must be something specific to your files.

Comment: You can prevent Ghostscript from embedding some fonts that were not embedded in the original file using this option (here, used with always-available fonts): `-c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [/Courier /Courier-Bold /Courier-Oblique /Courier-BoldOblique /Helvetica /Helvetica-Bold /Helvetica-Oblique /Helvetica-BoldOblique /Times-Roman /Times-Bold /Times-Italic /Times-BoldItalic /Symbol /ZapfDingbats /Arial]>> setdistillerparams" `

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [Multivalent](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/index.html) [Compress](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/pdf/Compress.html) tool. It has an (experimental) option to subset embedded fonts that might make your PDF much smaller. It also contains a lot of switches that allow for better compression, sometimes at the cost of quality (JPEG compression of bitmaps, for example).

Unfortunately, the most recent version of Multivalent does no longer include the tools. Google for `Multivalent20060102.jar`, that version still includes them. To run Compress:

```
java -classpath /path/to/Multivalent20060102.jar tool.pdf.Compress [options] <pdf file>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll look into Multivalent.

Comment: I downloaded the Multivalent jar file you referenced. I can run it with the -max option and the output file is significantly smaller but I can't view it with GS or Acrobat. 

The documentation for the -max or -compact options say that I need a "compact aware" viewer and that Adobe reader is not. The doc states that the Multivalent viewer is "compact aware" but i get a bunch of errors when trying to view the file with it.

There are some other command line options that I can play around with. I'll keep trying.

Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: The "compact PDF" format is an unofficial modification to the PDF standard by (I think) the Multivalent authors. Unless you don't need the PDF to be viewable on standard PDF readers, I would avoid using this option.